# Install Cygwin SSH Client without SSH server

Tags: windows-7, command-line, ssh

I am trying to use SSH from the Windows 7 command line as a client only. I CANNOT use a GUI.

Is Cygwin the best (easiest) option?

If so, how do I remove the server capabilities as this workstation will only be a client?

Comment: Cygwin doesn't install an SSH server? I don't think there's anything you need to remove. Do a minimal install and add ssh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @pjc50

Cigwyn default installs as a client.  Configuration is required to make it a server.

From [install Cygwin as Client and Server](http://ftp.perforce.com/perforce/tools/benchmarks/browse/doc/cygwin.html)

> At a minimum, to setup SSHD you must open a Cygwin window (by double clicking the Cygwin icon) and type:

```
ssh-host-config
```

> You will prompted to answer a few questions. The questions will vary depending on whether you want to run SSHD as a service or not. Once completed, start the SSHD server.    
> Started as a service:

```
net start sshd
```

> Started on the command line within a Cygwin shell:

```
/cygwin/sbin/sshd
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use [Plink](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) from the author of putty. It's a standalone .exe file which does just that - connect via SSH/Telnet to remote server on the command line.

Comment: It makes a very poor SSH client, however, due to the complete (and intentional) lack of terminal emulation.